How to create unique/strong type definitions of other types and validation functions for them in C++?
I've recently watched an interesting video about domain modeling in F#, and I wanted to apply some of the concepts to my C++ code.
For example, I currently have a class Window that has a member function clear(int r, int g, int b, int a). The function is supposed to clear the window with the provided color values. I want to give a unique type name to the parameters, such as ColorComponent so the function would become clear(ColorComponent r, ColorComponent g, ColorComponent b, ColorComponent b). I also want to create a validation function so that the input to the function would always be valid and I wouldn't need to perform checks inside every function that takes this form of input. In this case, I want the values to be in the range 0-255.
in my current code I have this:
int validateColor(int r) {
    return (r >= 0 && r <= 255) ? r : 255; // 255 is the default value
}

I've seen different ways of doing it online like making template classes:
template <class Tag, typename T>
class StrongTypedef
{
private:
   T value;
}

struct Color : StrongTypedef<Color, int> {};

Ideally, I'd be able to create unique types and then have different validations for each one. What would be the best way of going about this? Also, is this a good way to think about this in general or am I just over complicating things?

Unrelated: Why have separate arguments for the color components? Why not just clear(const Color&) where Color has r, g, b, a members?

If each component of a Color is bound to the value 0-255, that sounds like you want an actual type and not just a strong typedef.  What happens if somebody, somewhere, forgets to call your validateColor equivalent?  The Color type should maintain its own invariant.

If your color components are limited to the 0-255 range, then use a uint8_t type, compile with warnings enabled, and let the compiler warn you about the narrowing conversions.

I've done something like this but... if you want to let the "StrongTypedef" to behave like the underlying type (e.g. T can be copyable/moveable/non-copyable/non-moveable classes too) it is a lot more work. So you might want to limit T to integral types only

@TedLyngmo I did it this way just to be consistent with the openGL API, which has this function:
void glClearColor(  GLfloat red,
GLfloat green,
GLfloat blue,
GLfloat alpha);
I could also replace it with a single parameter like you mentioned.

@YakovGalka I was thinking of just using uint8_t, but I wanted to avoid the possibility of a value that's out of the range of 0-255 like 300 being turned into 44 implicitly. I'd much rather have a definitive type checking mechanism so that it'd never be possible to pass a value like that through user input

You should check boost.safe_numerics safe_signed_range.

clear(int r, int g, int b, int b) is not valid. Two parameters can't have the same name. This is not a [mcve].

It's absolutely possible to write strong types with value range guarantees (like this rather elderly example), but there are a few problems. You could add overloads accepting a larger type and doing "safe" narrowing conversion by hand, but you should just enable compiler warnings for these in the first place.

Finally, adding type tags is easy, but then you may need some conversion support (eg. each colour should be scalable by alpha if you're doing a weighted sum)
